# PIE.htc не работает в IE9

Tags: css3, internet-explorer

Нужно сделать так, чтобы линейный css3 градиент работал в IE 9. Скачал и прикрутил к проекту PIE.htc.
Если смотреть через IEtester, то в IE8 все работает отлично - все градиенты и прочие плюшки CSS3 есть. А вот IE9 игнорирует все включения пая.

В чём может быть проблема? Что можно сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ может, этот сервис поможет

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос нашёл в западных интернетах. Не самое красивое, но рабочее. Вдруг кому пригодится.

В HTML пишем

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<style>
    body {
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#528500', endColorstr='#91b800');
        behavior: url(js/ie9-gradient-fix.htc);
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Ссылка для загрузки ie9-gradient-fix.htc: http://abouthalf.com/examples/ie9roundedbackgrounds/htc.zip

Если его не использовать - градиенты тоже будут работать, но лично у меня пропало скругление border-radius

Comment: в ИЕ9 при градиенте border-radius не работет, как вариант для ИЕ9 использовать вместо градиента box-shadow

Comment: В ИЕ9 не работают вместе градиент с бордер-радиусом, возможно поэтому в Bootstrap3 отказались от градиентов =)